# create input mask for MMM-dd-yyyy format to enter only valid month short names for MMM in angular

Tags: angular, masking

I have added input mask for my datepicker using `angular2-text-mask` to get date in `MMM-dd-yyyy` (eg. Jan-01-2022) format. My question is, can we restrict user from entering any combination of letters for month short name like `'xyz' or 'abc'` using mask?
the mask format I am using is :

```
maskFormat = [/[A-Za-z]/, /[A-Za-z]/, /[A-Za-z]/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

Thanks.